# rotate tspan element in svg?

Tags: css, svg

in **tspan** we have rotate attribute which rotates each character but i want to rotate whole **tspan** as one and `transform="rotate(90)"` doesnt works?

How can i achieve it?

```html
<svg >
  <text x="10" y="30" style="font-size:12pt;">
    F
    <tspan>a</tspan>
    <tspan transform="rotate(90)"fill="red">lab</tspan>
    <tspan >l</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I wish word `lab` could be rotated

Comment: I think you cannot rotate a tspan, you can do it on a text

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest separate text for 3 tspan. Then you can use `transform:rotate()` on text.

See below example.

```html
<!--Rotate Example:-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text x="10" y="30" style="font-size:12pt;">
    F
    <tspan>a</tspan>
  </text>
  <text x="35" y="30" style="font-size:12pt;" transform="rotate(90 45 25)">
    <tspan fill="red">lab</tspan>
  </text>
  <text x="60" y="30" style="font-size:12pt;">
    <tspan >l</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>

<!--Original:-->
<svg >
  <text x="10" y="30" style="font-size:12pt;">
    F
    <tspan>a</tspan>
    <tspan fill="red">lab</tspan>
    <tspan >l</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/jybs79v1/

Comment: it rotates individual character.. not the whole tspan

Comment: not really, what is the purpose of tspan if i write text this way

Comment: The `transform` attribute is not allowed on a `<tspan>`. Tspan is mainly intended for styling effects such as changing font, size, colour etc.  If it had all the same features as the `<text>` element, there would be no use point in its existenmce.  If you want to apply a transform to a segment of text, then you need to use a `<text>` element.